# What do you call this type of argument?

Tags: single-word-requests

I like to have a friendly debate, but a lot of time people just come up with nonsense arguments like "Yeah but I'm right because you are stupid.". They are meant to be insults, but is there a word for this type of argument?

Comment: @Lawrence fixed

Comment: It's often referred to as  ***argument by invective***. [See here for examples from published books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&biw=1600&bih=792&tbm=bks&q=%22argument+by+invective%22+&oq=%22argument+by+invective%22+&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7851.7851.0.8150.1.1.0.0.0.0.47.47.1.1.0.dummy_maps_web_fallback...0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.3klFk78gUZ0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an attack is called an [ad hominem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem). It is considered to be a [fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_fallacy).

> From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem):
>
> Ad hominem (Latin for "to the man" or "to the person"), short for argumentum ad hominem, is where an argument is rebutted by attacking the character, motive, or other attribute of the person making the argument, or persons associated with the argument, rather than attacking the substance of the argument itself.

Comment: Hi @Scripter1000, quoting appropriate selections from your sources allows your answer to stand on its own. I've added one for you; feel free to [edit] further or to roll it back.

Comment: But please check for duplicates. 'Ad hominem' has been given before.